# Set custom shortcuts in Adobe Animate

Tags: animation, adobe, keyboard-shortcuts, easeinout

I'm using Adobe Animate for quite some time. I use Ease-In and Ease-out quite a lot when I animate different motions. Sadly, manually setting them for each motion tween is time consuming (I know, it takes a few clicks but as animator it is crucial :) )

I have checked in the keyboard shortcut menu but sadly I did not find what I am looking for.
I would appreciate your help, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out! [This link](https://helpx.adobe.com/il_en/animate/using/automating-tasks-commands-menu.html) helped me.

Step 1: Open Window -> History.
Make your specific action (In my example it is Ease-In in the Classic Motion Tween).
Step 2: The action will be stored in the History window.
Click on your action in the history window and choose "save selected steps as a command". Name your command how you want.
You can check in the "Commands" tab that your action is saved as a command!

Step 3: Go to Edit -> Keyboard Shortcuts. Find your command (What ever you named it...) and then apply a shortcut to it! Done!

These small steps really saves ton of time when animating lots and lots of objects and symbols.